# Unexpected import behavior: non-existing module imported

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, setuptools

I have a torch extension (but I think the error I get is independent of torch), let's call it `foo`, that is built with `setuptools`. However, it depends on whether there is a GPU available in the system, in which case some CUDA code is compiled:

```py
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import CppExtension, BuildExtension, CUDAExtension

if cuda_available:
    ext = CUDAExtension(
            'foo_gpu',
            prefixed(prefix, ['foo.cpp', 'foo_kernel.cu']),
            define_macros=[('COMPILE_CUDA', '1')])
else:
    ext = CppExtension(
            'foo_cpu',
            prefixed(prefix, ['foo.cpp']))

setup(name=ext.name,
      version='1.0.0',
      ext_modules=[ext_module],
      extra_compile_args=['-mmacosx-version-min=10.9'],
      cmdclass={'build_ext': BuildExtension})
```

Notice how the module is compiled to be either `foo_gpu` or `foo_cpu`.

Later, I import it as follows:

```py
try:
    import foo_gpu as foo_backend
    CUDA_SUPPORTED = True
except ImportError:
    CUDA_SUPPORTED = False
    # Try importing the cpu version
    try:
        import foo_cpu as foo_backend
    except ImportError:
        ...
```

Let's say I compile it with CUDA support, so `foo_gpu` goes into PIP (actually goes into PIP as `foo-gpu`, not sure why?)

Now, I uninstalled it, `pip uninstall foo-gpu`, and compile it with CPU support only, and pip shows `foo-cpu 1.0.0`.

*BUT*, now, when I run the import code above, it still finds `foo-gpu`, i.e., the first import statement succeeds! Even though it does not show up in `pip`.

---

**EDIT**. I checked `sys.path` and found there is one folder that contains something with `gpu` in my conda env:

```
$ ls ~/miniconda3/envs/cpu_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/foo_cpu-1.0.0-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ 
 EGG-INFO
 __pycache__
 foo_cpu.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
 foo_cpu.py
 foo_gpu.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

But how should it get there? In this env (`cpu_env`), I never compiled with GPU support. Are there some caches that get invoked?

Comment: "*`foo_gpu` goes into PIP (actually goes into PIP as `foo-gpu`, not sure why?)*"

PyPI renames packages to prevent having both `foo_gpu` and `foo-gpu` as 2 different packages.

Comment: In this env (cpu_env), I never compiled with GPU support.Are you sure? you did not provide the full session log but to me it seems you mistyped the environment and compiled for gpu in the cpu env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the GPU build in was cached by setuptools (`build/`, `dist/`, etc.) and also installed!